# Maven onejar plugin, get a properties file

Tags: java, maven, uberjar

I am using the Maven onejar plugin (https://code.google.com/p/onejar-maven-plugin/) to create an uberjar.

I want to access a properties file which is in the root of my classpath like this:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();

        try {
            prop.load(new FileInputStream("Db.properties"));

            driver = prop.getProperty("driver");
            url = prop.getProperty("url");
            username = prop.getProperty("username");
            password = prop.getProperty("password");

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            LOG.debug(ex.toString());
        }   

        conn = null;
```

My log4j.properties file which is in the same directory is found because i can do logging... What is my problem? :/
But the Db.properties isnt found.

Comment: Is Db.properties packaged in the jar?

Comment: Yeah i am opening my reminder.one-jar.jar -> main -> reminder.jar and in this jar file is my Db.properties file in the same path as log4j.properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FileInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html) is used to load resources from files located on the file system.  Files inside a jar are not on the file system.  You need to use a different [InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html).

For this case, using the [ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) method would be advised.  It returns an InputStream resource found on the classpath.  Something like:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/Db.properties");
```

should work.  Or for convenience:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Db.properties");
```

Of note, the reason the `log4j.properties` works is because Log4j by design can load configuration files in the root classpath.

Comment: Mh... it still doesnt work..
InputStream i = getClass().getResourceAsStream("Db.properties");
        
     try {
      prop.load((FileInputStream)i);

Comment: I got it! i added a Slash in front of Db.properties! Thank you.